# How to use variable in sh curl groovy using quotest?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, sh, quotes

i have a script

```
Date date = new Date()
String datePart = date.format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")

sh "curl 'www.link.com' --json '{"datas": "${datePart}"}'"
```

result is negative...

Ideally result should be `curl 'www.link.com' --json '{"datas": "2021-04-07 13:00:00"}'`

How could i fix it? i need all quotes to be like in my example and important is that variable should work

Comment: Escape each doublequote or use triple doublequoted string `sh """..."""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this it should work so use it like this

`sh "curl 'www.link.com' --json \'{\"datas\": \"${datePart}\"}'"`

OR another alternatives

`"curl 'www.link.com' --json \"{\\\"datas\\\": \\\"${datePart}\\\"}\""`